# Set key value pairs in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, bash4

I have a shell script to bootstrap my machine: https://github.com/pathikrit/mac-setup-script/blob/master/setup.sh

I have these few lines of code to setup git:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

I would like to extract that out to an associative array (a dictionary/hashmap) at the top and call that in a single line of code. How can I do that in bash 4+?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Create the associative array
declare -A opts
opts[rerere.enabled]=true
opts[branch.autosetuprebase]=always
opts[credential.helper]=osxkeychain

# Use the associative array
for k in "${!opts[@]}"
do
    git config --global "$k" "${opts[$k]}"
done
```